# Reconnection to mqtt broker fails when using own mosquitto broker on AWS EC2 ubuntu Instance

Tags: linux, mqtt, esp8266, mosquitto, arduino-esp8266

I was using mosquito's test mqtt broker before (i.e. test.mosquitto.org) on my esp8266 with reconnection code i.e. if connection is broken due to router reset then it will reconnect to broker when internet is back. And its working fine. I had used same code with Cloud Mqtt broker and it was working perfectly too. But now when I hosted my own mosquitto broker like in this tutorial [MQTT broker on AWS EC2](https://medium.com/@achildrenmile/mqtt-broker-on-aws-ec2-hands-on-install-configure-test-out-f12dd2f5c9d0) it stopped reconnecting after router reset. Below is my code on ESP8266:-

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>       

const char* topic = "someTopic";
String clientId = "randomClientId";
const char* mqttServer = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.compute.amazonaws.com";
const int mqttPort = 1883;

PubSubClient client(espClient);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  client.setServer(mqttServer, mqttPort);
  client.setCallback(callback);
  lastReconnectAttempt = 0;
  delay(500);
}

boolean reconnect() {
    clientId += String(random(0xffff), HEX);
    if (client.connect(clientId.c_str())) {
      client.subscribe(topic);
    } 
  return client.connected();
}

void loop() {
  if (!client.connected()) 
  {
    long now = millis();
    if (now - lastReconnectAttempt > 5000) 
    {
      lastReconnectAttempt = now;
      if (reconnect()) 
      {
        lastReconnectAttempt = 0;
      }
    }
  } else 
  {
    client.loop();
  }  
}
```

Please let me know if someone knows the reason of this.

Comment: What do the broker logs show?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't ever connect to wifi... how is it possibly supposed to work?